# Why: cannot read property getBoundingClientRect of null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the most suprising thing i've ever seen. Consider this code:

```js
getElementDims = (elem, task) => {
        this.setState( prevState => {
            const taskDims = {...prevState.taskDims};
            taskDims[task.id] = true;
            taskDims[task.id] = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
            //the error occured from the above line of code
            return {taskDims}
        })
        
        console.log(elem.getBoundingClientRect())
        //if the setState() is commented out, logs the right values without error
    }
    taskRows = () => {
        const {display, directTasks, tasks, rootParent} = this.state;
        return directTasks[display]
        .filter(directTask => directTask.rootParent === rootParent)
        .map(directTask => {
            const childTasks = () => {
                return tasks[display]
                .filter(task => task.biggestParentInDisplay === directTask.biggestParentInDisplay)
                .map(task => {
                    return <div className = 'task' style={{
                        gridColumn: `${task.colStart - directTask.colStart + 1 } / span ${length(task)}`,
                        gridRowStart: task.level + ' / span 1',
                        backgroundColor: `rgba(42, ${255 - (55 / task.level) }, 139, 0.76)`,
                        gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${length(task)}, 1fr)`,
                    }}>
                        {progress(task)}
                        <p className='tlTaskName'>{task.name}</p>
                    </div>
                })
            }

            const onDown = (e, task) => {
                this.isDragging = true;
                this.setState({
                    gridUnit: length(task) / this.state.taskDims[task.id].width,
                })
                console.log(e.pageX, this.state.taskDims[task.id].left)
            }
            return <div 
                className = 'directTask' 
                style = {{
                    gridColumn: `${this.state.dragX || directTask.colStart + 1} / span ${length(directTask)}`,
                    gridTemplateColumns: `repeat( ${length(directTask)} , 1fr)`,
                    gridTemplateRows: "repeat(" + directTask.rows + ", 1fr)"
                }}
                ref={e => this.getElementDims(e, directTask)}
                onPointerDown={e => onDown(e, directTask)}
            >
                {childTasks()}
            </div>
        })
    }
            
    render(){
        return(
            <div className = 'timeline' style={{
                display: "grid",
                gridTemplateColumns: "auto [start] 1fr",
                gridTemplateRows: "100px repeat(" + this.state.rows + ", 150px)",
            }} >
                {this.tasksRows()}
            </div>
         )
    }
```

My only question is: why? I mean how it's possible to if i read the property inside setState, it's null, if i read inside a console.log, it's not null. I don't know what will be relevant to solve the problem from my code, please let me know if something important is missing.

Comment: The `ref` callback function will be called with the element when it is mounted, and called again with `null` when the element is unmounted. You need to make sure `elem` is set before you use it, i.e. make sure you don't use it when the element is unmounting.

Comment: If i wrap it inside an if statement which checks if elem is not null, it returns an inifinte loop :/

Comment: That's frustrating. Could you include your entire component? It's hard to tell what might be wrong from the code currently in your question.

Comment: Ouh it will be hard a bit, but i try to expand the snippet to all relevant code (i think)

Comment: It logs a new error now: `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Comment: It's sure that the problem is with setState. Without it, the function is called just once. But i think setState forces the function to recall itself somehow.

Comment: It's possible that as you said, the function is also called on unmount, and setState causes a mount again, then unmount, mount and so on?

Comment: Have you tried putting `elem.getBoundingClientRect()` in a variable before `setState` and then using that variable in `setState`? Since `setState` is asynchronous, that might cause some problems.

Comment: Yes... that was my last try: `            if(elem){
                const dims = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
                this.setState({
                    taskDims: dims
                });
                console.log(elem.getBoundingClientRect());
            }`

Comment: Where is `directTasks` and `display` coming from in `directTasks[display]`? I'm having a hard time understanding the context. Try putting a `key` prop on the `divs` returned from `taskRows` or it might be that they are re-created every time, calling the `ref` callback every render, and the indefinite loop happens.

Comment: That's why i said it will be hard, because the component has 900 lines of code. The directTasks is an object, the display is the key of the directTasks, both come from the state. Sorry, i cut it out. But i put it back.