# Why i can't read react component's properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why i can't read the component's arguments? Even if i copy the path from the chrome console, it returns undefined. It's a long id, but i don't think that should be a problem. Any ideas why this happen?

```
componentDidMount(){
  console.log(this)
  // the above code logs the argument below too
  console.log(this["-LH4IZUHM7LDbFKghUS6"])
  // logs undefined
}
```

With the following JSX:

```
<div ref={e => this[e.id}></div>
```

Comment: Where does `element` come from in your `ref` callback? Also, `this[element.id` is not valid syntax.

Comment: @Tholle you know the story... I don't know what to do the `ref` thing. My idea was to store the ref as the component's property, then set the state from it at componentDidMount. But now, i can't even read it.

Comment: Maybe its value is `undefined`? If you do `console.dir(this)`, you can more easily see what the property values are.

Comment: You have a typo and forgot the `]` in the `ref={` callback. You must assign a value to the result too,eg. `ref={el => this[el.id] = el}` if you want to be able to access it. Although I doubt this is a best practice approach, what are you *actually* trying to do in general terms?

Comment: It's simple... i thought first.. but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51351685/why-cannot-read-property-getboundingclientrect-of-null?noredirect=1#comment89676410_51351685 . I need to read the dimensions of an array of dom elements. But i can't set the state of it from ref.

Comment: @DorLask your post does not contain the result of that `console.log(this)`, so: can you copy-paste the data from your dev console into your post? (not as a comment reply). Also, where is the rest of your component code? There is nothing for readers to currently believe you when you say that property should even exist at all: who knows what `e => this[e.id]` even does, given that `this[e.id]` isn't tied to anything. As far as readers can tell, that does absolutely nothing.

Comment: You [can access component instance's properties from within ref function](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpPENV?editors=1010) if it's bound to that instance or is an arrow function that does not have context. So it seems that there is just no such property that you're looking for. Please clarify the question.